# Use jQuery to wrap brackets text after first line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
<p>
    <strong>FITZGERALD</strong> (CONT’D)<br>
    Shut up, boy, you don’t get no say in this.<br>
    (back to Henry)<br>
    And in case you hadn’t noticed, Captain, we’re seventeen men short of what we were.
    (off the wounded trapper)<br>
    Eighteen before long.
</p>
```

I want to add class `.wi-dialog` for `p` and wrap each text in brackets `(` `)` like `<span class="wi-remark">(` `)</span>` but after first `<br>`

So my paragraph will look like this

```
<p class="wi-dialog">
    <strong>FITZGERALD</strong> (CONT’D)<br>
    Shut up, boy, you don’t get no say in this.<br>
    <span class="wi-remark">(back to Henry)</span><br>
    And in case you hadn’t noticed, Captain, we’re seventeen men short of what we were.
    <span class="wi-remark">(off the wounded trapper)</span><br>
    Eighteen before long.
</p>
```

I can not solve the problem with the first line. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dialog = $( "p:has(strong)" ).addClass( "wi-dialog" );

    dialog.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/.*?(\(.*?\)).*?/g, '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>') });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dialog = $( "p:has(strong)" ).addClass( "wi-dialog" );
  dialog.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/(?<=\n)\s*(\(.*?\)).*?/g, '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>') });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>FITZGERALD</strong> (CONT’D)<br>
  Shut up, boy, you don’t get no say in this.<br>
  (back to Henry)<br>
  And in case you hadn’t noticed, Captain, we’re seventeen men short of what we were.
  (off the wounded trapper)<br>
  Eighteen before long.
</p>
```

Comment: I am glad to help

Comment: I have error on this line `dialog.html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/(?<=\n)\s*(\(.*?\)).*?/g, '<span class="wi-remark">$&</span>') });`

Comment: What browser and version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group?noredirect=1&lq=1 and decided that the problem is regular expression. iphone se and 6 >

Comment: What phone are you using? I just ran a test on iPhone 8 Plus without a problem.

Comment: iphone se and 6. SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

Comment: U can check it on this page https://kinoscenariy.com/screenplay/vo-vse-tyazhkie/ in russian but..

Comment: I think I've found the solution, but first can you start a new question and post the link here and then I can post the answer on there, because it's not really fair to change your question on here after an answer has already been accepted