# JS: shorten search results by the words, which were found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I am searching for the title and description in my application and the task is to shorten search results. For example, if the description is too long (more than 2 lines) the result should be shortened to one or two lines of text with a found word highlighted.

Here's the example from algolia:
[image]

Here's what I've tried so far, but it's not working as expected:

```
  const truncateHighlightedText = (
    sentence,
    searchExpression,
    truncateLength
  ) => {
    const pattern = new RegExp(
      '\\b.{1,' +
        truncateLength +
        '}\\b' +
        searchExpression +
        '\\b.{1,' +
        truncateLength +
        '}\\b',
      'i'
    );

    return sentence.match(pattern);
  };


const sentence = "Testsdfgbsegsegsrewgserwfgvsrevfse  ewrwer wergwregew    erwgrewgwerg   erwgwr eerg rg g er egr ew  erger  rtggrt tr ert tr tr tg tgr gtr  gtr egrt rtg trg rg e eg";
const searchExpression = "egseg";
const truncateLength = 20;


const result = truncateHighlightedText(sentence, searchExpression, truncateLength);
console.log(result);
```

`https://jsfiddle.net/dwr3qgs0/1/`

What can be the best approach for this task?

Comment: What sort of match were you hoping for given the sentence there? The only standalone `eg` is at the very end of the string, which doesn't match because the `.{1` requires at least one character afterwards

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was hoping for searchExpression and a few words from both sides of this word. e.g.  Testsdfgbs`egseg`srewgserwfgvsrevfse  ewrwer

Comment: Even though the `eg` isn't a standalone word there?

Comment: @CertainPerformance It's pretty ok, cause I wanted to add '...' from both sides of the line, but it will be also great to show standalone words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently doesn't match anything for 2 reasons:

- You're using word boundaries with `\b`, which means that only a match for the standalone word will work. In the code in your question, `egseg` is not a standalone word anywhere. In the code in the fiddle, `eg` is a standalone word, but it exists at the very end of the string
- You're requiring *at least one* character before and after the matched word with your `{1,' + truncateLength + '}`. This is why, in the fiddle, the `eg` isn't matched.

If you want to match the `searchExpression` *anywhere*, remove the word boundaries, and use `{0,`, not `{1,`, in case the match is at the beginning or end of the string:

```js
const truncateHighlightedText = (
  sentence,
  searchExpression,
  truncateLength
) => {
  const pattern = new RegExp(
    '\\b.{0,' +
    truncateLength +
    '}' +
    searchExpression +
    '.{0,' +
    truncateLength +
    '}\\b',
    'i'
  );
  console.log(pattern)

  return sentence.match(pattern);
};


const sentence = "Testsdfgbsegsegsrewgserwfgvsrevfse  ewrwer wergwregew    erwgrewgwerg   erwgwr eerg rg g er egr ew  erger  rtggrt tr ert tr tr tg tgr gtr  gtr egrt rtg trg rg e eg";
const searchExpression = "egseg";
const truncateLength = 30;


const result = truncateHighlightedText(sentence, searchExpression, truncateLength);
console.log(result);
```

To add `...`s to the ends which contain additional unshown characters, optionally capture a character before and after the match in lookaround tokens and add `...`s if they've captured anything:

```js
const truncateHighlightedText = (
  sentence,
  searchExpression,
  truncateLength
) => {
  const pattern = new RegExp(
    '(?<=(.)?)\\b.{0,' +
    truncateLength +
    '}' +
    searchExpression +
    '.{0,' +
    truncateLength +
    '}\\b(?=(.)?)',
    'i'
  );
  const match = sentence.match(pattern);
  return (match[1] ? '...' : '') + match[0] + (match[2] ? '...' : '');
};


const sentence = "Testsdfgbsegsegsrewgserwfgvsrevfse  ewrwer wergwregew    erwgrewgwerg   erwgwr eerg rg g er egr ew  erger  rtggrt tr ert tr tr tg tgr gtr  gtr egrt rtg trg rg e eg";
const searchExpression = "egseg";
const truncateLength = 30;


const result = truncateHighlightedText(sentence, searchExpression, truncateLength);
console.log(result);
```

Without lookbehind, use capturing groups everywhere instead of the `match[0]`:

```js
const truncateHighlightedText = (
  sentence,
  searchExpression,
  truncateLength
) => {
  const pattern = new RegExp(
    '(.)?(\\b.{0,' +
    truncateLength +
    '}' +
    searchExpression +
    '.{0,' +
    truncateLength +
    '})\\b(.)?',
    'i'
  );
  const match = sentence.match(pattern);
  return (match[1] ? '...' : '') + match[2] + (match[3] ? '...' : '');
};


const sentence = "Testsdfgbsegsegsrewgserwfgvsrevfse  ewrwer wergwregew    erwgrewgwerg   erwgwr eerg rg g er egr ew  erger  rtggrt tr ert tr tr tg tgr gtr  gtr egrt rtg trg rg e eg";
const searchExpression = "egseg";
const truncateLength = 30;


const result = truncateHighlightedText(sentence, searchExpression, truncateLength);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Also, what's the right way to add `...`? In your example, it should be added at the end of the string. If the sentence is cut from both ends, then the `...` should be at both ends pf a string.

Comment: See edit, capture in a lookaround, then examine the match array

Comment: Just want to clarify, is it possible to make this regexp cross-browser? As I see, look-back won't work in older browser and safari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Without lookbehind, use capturing groups everywhere to extract the substrings