# React app runs on Chrome but displays a blankpage on safari

Tags: reactjs, regex, safari

I have a react app that was created with create-react-app. Everything works perfectly on chrome but the app crashes on safari and the following error is in the safari console:

"SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"

[Error message as displayed in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbJK2.png)

[Line where the error occurs in vendors~main.chunk.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N09u.png)

I am completely unsure of what to do to fix this issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Works in Chrome, but breaks in Safari: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name /(?<=\/)(\[^#\]+)(?=#\*)/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group)

Comment: I also had this same issue when using the `replaceAll()` method. I suspect that when the JavaScript is minified with `npm build`, it could lead to a regular expression that has issues on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a capturing group:

```js
const regex = /{([$0-9a-zA-Z_]+)(?=.*})/g
const variable = []
let m;
while (m = regex.exec(segment)) {
  variable.push(m[1])
}
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/y0F0hH/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [$0-9a-zA-Z_]+           any character of: '$', '0' to '9', 'a'
                             to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '_' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```