# Regex lookbehind not supported in Safari - how to achieve the same?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regext `(?<=")[^"]+(?=")|\w{3,}/g`.
However I noticed it's not working in safari: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

How can I achieve the same that work in Safari as well? I am looking for a regex or vanilla JS solution.

What it needs to achieve:

If I input: `xyz I am in the United States` the output should be:

```
["xyz", "the", "United", "States"]
```

If I input `xyz I am "in the United States"` the output. should be:

```
["xyz", "in the United States"]
```

So it should discard all the words that:

- have less than 2 characters AND are not inside the double quotes
- if the 1 or 2 characters words are inside the double quotes, than it should not discard them

In summary same functionality that puts string into array, but works with Safari too...

Please help

Comment: What if there is a word in quotes that has fewer than 3 characters, like `xyz "oh" well`? Your regex would include "oh"...

Comment: yes, if it is in quotes, then is should stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capture groups:

```js
function words(s) {
    var regex = /"([^"]+)"|(\w{3,})/g;
    var result = [];
    while (true) {
        var match = regex.exec(s);
        if (!match) break;
        result.push(match[match[1] ? 1 : 2]);
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(words('xyz I am in the United States'));
console.log(words('xyz I am "in the United States"'));
```

The above solution could be done easier with `.matchAll` and destructuring, but I suppose I shouldn't take the risk to use newer features, since you have no support for look behind.

Alternatively, you can use `replace`, but actually throw away the main effect of it, and just use the side effect:

```js
function words(s) {
    var result = [];
    s.replace(/"([^"]+)"|(\w{3,})/g, (_, quoted, word) => 
        result.push(quoted || word)
    );
    return result;
}
console.log(words('xyz I am in the United States'));
console.log(words('xyz I am "in the United States"'));
```

Comment: thank you. That works like a charm! Any idea if it's possible somehow to fix the eslint warning `Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment  no-cond-assign` before the `while` loop? More brakets seem to fix that. Do you think it would be a good solution to leave it like `while ((match = regex.exec(s))`?

Comment: Updated the loop so it no longer has an assignment in the `while` condition, and added an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this `regex` `lookbehind` issue with **Safari** today and (eventually) came up with a solution using:

- `split()`
- `replace()` / `replaceAll()`

The following working example (using the same methods) is one approach to getting around the issue that in June 2022, **Safari** does not (yet) understand `regex` `lookbehinds`.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const logOutput = (input) => {

  let quotedSection = (input.includes('"')) ? input.split('"')[1].split('"')[0] : '';
  let quotedSectionReplacement = quotedSection.replaceAll(' ', '^^');
  let inputString = input.replace(`"${quotedSection}"`, quotedSectionReplacement);

  let inputArray = inputString.split(' ');
  let outputArray = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
  
    if (inputArray[i].length > 2) {
    
      outputArray.push(inputArray[i].replaceAll('^^', ' '));
    }
  }
  
  console.log(outputArray);
}

logOutput( 'xyz I am in the United States');
logOutput('xyz I am "in the United States"');
```