# Need the next regex apply only in tags anchor

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next string:

```
<a href="https://lac.wetlands.org/" class="com-link" target="_blank"><mark class="hl_yellow"><b>Fundación Humedales/Wetlands International:</b></mark></a><mark class="hl_yellow"><b> </b></mark><a href="https://twitter.com/fundachumedales?lang=en" class="com-link" target="_blank">Twitter </a>/ <a href="https://es-la.facebook.com/fundacion.humedales/" class="com-link" target="_blank">Facebook</a> / Instagram. Por el Día de los Humedales, junto al Museo Scasso lanzó <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl0lgozO_HU&amp;feature=youtu.be" class="com-link" target="_blank">este video</a>
```

I need to match all the classes of the tags < a > only.

I have this regex:

(?:class|className)=(?:["']\W+\s*(?:\w+)()?"'['"]/g;

But its apply in every tag (Like < mark >). In need to apply only in tags a but i cant get it. Any help ?strong text

Comment: Don't use regex on HTML. [HTML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2487517).  
 Use a DOM parser.

Comment: I cant use that, i really need that regex work only in tags a

Comment: Haven't you posed the exact question today before and got the answer to use a parser instead? And **yes**, you can use one instead of a regex that won't cover all the cases.

Comment: Everything looks like a nail when the only tool you know how to use is a hammer

Comment: I am not native english speaker so i cant tell you exactly why, but dom parser is not an option for me. I really need a regex that match in the clases of tags < a > only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would match the class attribute in `a` tags:

```
(?<=<a)(?:.(?!<\/a>))*?class="([^"]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/csdD2V/1)

The Key part is `(?:.(?!<\/a>))*?` where you check that `</a>` doesn't occur before finding `classe="`

Comment: Thats was exactly was i need. Thanks you very much!!!!!!

Comment: That regex works greats but, we find recently thats regex breaks on safari, for compatibility issues. Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group for more info. The solutions for this was change (?<=<a) part for (?:<a)