# safari SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name evaluateWithScopeExtension

Tags: javascript, replace, safari

safari SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name evaluateWithScopeExtension

```
'系统订单号:1717985597717212672;系统订单号:1718005616957731072;'.replace(/(?<=订单号:(\d+,)*)\d+=|$/g, (m) => {
  console.log(`[logger-m] => `, m)
  return m
})
```

Comment: What are you expecting as the return value and what do you expect logger-m to log?

Comment: You're trying to use a positive look behind `(?<=` which [isn't supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in Safari as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe iOS's regular expression issue.
It's discussed on other article.
[Works in Chrome, but breaks in Safari: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name /(?<=\/)([^#]+)(?=#*)/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group)

Comment: Thank you!! The problem here is that the Safari browser is outdated.