# Safari Regular Expression Error: invalid group specifier name (innerHTML.replace(/(?<!\\)\\n|\n/g, '<br/>'))

Tags: angular, typescript, safari, angular13

The web page not working in the Safari browser and it's working fine on other browsers.

**Code**

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var ele = document.querySelector('.break-field');
    if (ele) {
      ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(/(?<!\\)\\n|\n/g, '<br/>')
    }
  }
```

**Error Message**

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
    promiseReactionJob
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Safari does not support lookbehind in regular expressions. Have you taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group)?

Answer (score 0):

Change regular expression into this `.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "<br/>");`