# How do I rewrite my regular expression so that it works in Safari?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I created a function a while back that capitalizes a string. The function applies a regular expression to determine if the first alphanumeric character is preceded by a non-alphanumeric character. The `search` method returns the index of the first alphanumeric character, should that be the case. Otherwise, the function simply converts the first character of the string to an uppercase character.

```
function capitalize(string: string) {
  const match = string.search(/(?<=[^[a-z]|[0-9]\s])[a-z]|[0-9]/i);
  const index = match === -1 ? 0 : match;

  const characters = string.toLowerCase().split('');
  characters[index] = characters[index].toUpperCase();

  return characters.join('');
}
```

However, it turns out that this breaks in Safari, because the regular expression relies on a positive look-behind, and Safari does not support that, [as far as I can tell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group).

How could I rewrite this regular expression, so that it works in Safari as well (no look-behind)?

*I know that this can be done in multiple steps, but I would much prefer to use just one regular expression if that is possible.*

Comment: I think your current regex doesn't actually work. If the first character of the string is a alphanumeric already, it won't be matched since it's not preceded by anything. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Would a simply word boundary work for you?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. Because, if it does not match anything, then `index` is set to 0 anyway.

Comment: You were right, @Bergi. I could simply use `/[a-z]|[0-9]/`. I would use a word boundary if it did not also include the character for underscore. Anyway, I tested it out and it does yield the correct index.