# Regex to prevent double underscores at the beginning and the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a regex to match a url subpath. It looks like this

`^(?!^__.*__$).[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$`

I want to disable ONLY 2 underscores at the beginning and the end of the string because it's a reserved string. Any number of underscores other than 2 should be allowed

For example:

```
_should_work_
__should_work___
_should_work___
__should_not_work__
```

The problem now is even though I have more than 2 underscores, the regex will still not match

```
___should_work_but_doesnt__________
```

You can check out the regex here:

https://regex101.com/r/H9F1NN/1

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to do a positive match, like for example `^__[^_]+__$`, and reject the strings that do match the regex.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: [`^(?!__(?!_).*[^_]__$)\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/q07vvO/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble this 1 works but sadly it does not work on safari :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group

Comment: @KelokChan: So, if you want to `"disallow __test__ but allow anything else"`, which of the answers fit that criteria? I think your title, description and examples here are in sync, but there is a disconnect with the fiddle you gave.

Comment: Also, what should `__` (string made of two underscores), or `___` (string made of three underscores) give? Any is regex a must (if yes, why)?

Comment: @KelokChan Have you tested it on Safari? I can't see any reason why it should not work there, it does not contain any lookbehind, just lookaheads which are supported afaik. However for simplicity and compatibility I'd stick to [@PeterThoeny's answer with a slight modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154645/regex-to-prevent-double-underscores-at-the-beginning-and-the-end-of-the-string#comment132688364_75165744).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate the test, witch makes it easier:

```js
const regex = /^__(?:[^_]|[^_].*[^_])__$/;
['ok', 'ok_too', '_ok_', '_ok__', '__ok_too_', '__bad__', '__bad_as_well__',
 '__b__', '___ok__', '___o__', '___ok____'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, '=>', !regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
ok => true
ok_too => true
_ok_ => true
_ok__ => true
__ok_too_ => true
__bad__ => false
__bad_as_well__ => false
__b__ => false
___ok__ => true
___o__ => true
___ok____ => true
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `__` -- expect two underscores
- `(?:` -- start of non-capture group (for logical or)

  - `[^_]` -- expect a non-underscore char
- `|` -- logical or

  - `[^_].*[^_]` -- expect a non-underscore char, any number of chars, and a non-underscore char
- `)` -- end of non-capture group
- `__` -- expect two underscores
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Note that this regex avoids lookarounds, which is not universally supported.

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

**UPDATE 1**: Changed regex from `^__[^_].*[^_]__$` to `^__(?:[^_]|[^_].*[^_])__$` to account for singe char `__x__` too.

Comment: I like this idea but in my understanding e.g `__a__` should be false too. To fix this, you can simply add an optional group: `^__[^_](?:.*[^_])?__$`

Comment: @bobblebubble: Good point, I updated the regex with a logical `or` to support that corner case. Your regex is good too

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
^(?!_(?!_))(?!(?:.*[^_])?_$)[\w.-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jAsJSp/4).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!_(?!_))` - the string should not start with a `_` that is not immediately followed with another `_` char
- `(?!(?:.*[^_])?_$)` - the string can't end with a `_` that is immediately preceded with a char other than a `_` or at the start of string
- `[\w.-]+` - one or more letters, digit, underscores, dots or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This incorrectly fails on `___ok__` and `___ok____`

Comment: No, [both are matched fine](https://regex101.com/r/jAsJSp/3).

Comment: Try `['_ok_', '_ok__', '__ok_too_', '__bad__', '__bad_as_well__', '___ok__', '___ok____'].forEach(str => { console.log(str, '=>', /^(?!_(?!_))(?!(?:.*[^_])?_$)\w+$/.test(str)); });`. If I understand the OP and his examples, he wants to disallow *only* strings that have exactly 2 leading and trailing underscores, and allow strings with 1 or 3+ underscores on either side

Comment: @PeterThoeny Your understanding is not correct. See [OP  regex attempt fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/H9F1NN/1) where all expected cases are given.

Comment: Hmm, then there is a disconnect between the examples in the fiddle, and his title, description, and examples in the OP

Comment: Basically I want to disallow `__test__` but allow anything else if that helps. The original fiddle has been modified by someone so it's not the same anymore

Comment: @KelokChan If you want to disallow `__test__` you allow `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
^(?!^__[^_]+(_[^_]+)*__$).[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$
^(?!^__[^_].*(?<!_)__$).[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$
```

Where both `[^_]+(_[^_]+)*` and `[^_].*(?<!_)` match any string that does not start and end with an underscore.