# BabelJS does not warn for unsupported regex syntax with older Safari version

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have this function:

```js
function x(arg) { return arg.split(/(?<=\p{L})(?=\P{L})|(?<=\P{L})(?=\p{L})/ug); };
```

It doesn't work in Safari older than 16.4 ([caniuse data](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3F%3C%3D)), because of the lookbehind assertion. Instead, it produces a syntax error (as mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group))

However, BabelJS does not transpile it and also does not warn about it. I have specified targets as: `last 5 safari version`. [Link to babel playground](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=last%205%20safari%20version&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQEMBOBzAlIgb0UwFMoRMktsA6AZwAcAbGKVAelQH4AeAXgA6DAgBkAvrm6CACqIkAfbvwGzxkroOFr2IPAG5EYvUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.21.6&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

When I use babeljs with a list of targets, I assumed that the transpiled result will work on all those targets. I know there's no direct transpilation for this lookbehind. However, babeljs should at least generate a warning that the lookbehind is not supported in the targets specified.

Is there any warning flag in babeljs to enable this? Or is this usecase solvable with another tool?